# SQL - how to search for fields with no text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have data in field1 with 1-~50 blank spaces (not null, but no text). I need way to search for all these fields in order to trim.

***Select * from table1 where field1 = ' '*** does not capture records with more one space. Using >= or <= includes records with actual text which I don't want to update.

Is there any way to capture ONLY records with no actual text?

Comment: Select * from table1 where field1 = ' ' should work if its blank

Comment: @DanielMarcus By blank OP might mean multiple white spaces

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: But I'm also curious how I could do this search in Oracle SQL developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server trailing spaces are ignored. So a row with no spaces or 50 spaces will be returned by your query. Are you wanting only those with more than a single space and exclude those with only a single space? Or you don't want them if they have nothing but spaces. You could use replace for that.

```
select *
from table1
where replace(field1, ' ', 'x') = ''
```

Yes it is painfully easy to prove that trailing spaces are ignored.

```
with SpacesDemo as
(
    select ' ' as Spaces, 1 as NumSpaces union all
    select '          ', 10
)

select *
from SpacesDemo
where Spaces = ''
```

I suspect you have characters that are not spaces in your data.

Comment: Are you sure about that trailing spaces functionality? When I change query from ' ' to '    ' I get more/less results depending on how many spaces I query for.

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate this possibility further

Comment: Yes, he is sure @KarsD. You can [read about it here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces) among other places. The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate.

Comment: Just a word of caution, you may have other "white space" characters in your data like carriage returns, line feeds, tabs etc. These are not equal to an empty string so could cause you a challenge.

Comment: Thanks, I doubt that's the case but I'll keep it in mind. I think you've helped me solve the problem.

Comment: If I had this same problem in Oracle SQL developer, and the trailing spaces functionality did not apply, what would be the solution in that DBMS?

Comment: I am not the one to ask for that. I can't even spell Oracle correctly. I have not written a query in that environment in close to 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where field1 not like '%[^ ]%' and field1 like '% %';
```

You can include any fields you want in the character class, so this easily generalizes to whatever you might consider a space.

Comment: This query returned records with no text and with text, so sadly it did not solve my problem. Appreciate the answer though.

Comment: @KarsD . . . If you need at least one space, see the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like operator can be used similar to regex

```
select * from table1 where field1 LIKE '^[ ]{1,}'
```

Comment: Sql server does not support full regex, only basic pattern matching. Pretty sure this isn't going to work.

Comment: True but this doesn't work. Can you provide an example how this prevents rows with multiple spaces and returns rows with only 1 space?

Comment: OP requires criteria with one or more spaces.`{1,}` will make sure that there is atleast one space in the field

Comment: For regex it does, but this does not work in a query. Try the cte I posted and use your LIKE. It returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In Transact-SQL (SQLServer) there is [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function that removes white-space characters (or other depending on parameters) from the beginning and the end of a string .

Your query should look more less or like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE TRIM(field1) = '';
```

The similar functions are both in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) and [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: There is no need to trim. It could have 1,000 spaces and simply = '' will return it as long as there is nothing else in the column.

Comment: @SeanLange Do you know if it is the default behaviour in other DB engines or only in SQL Server?

Comment: I don't know that for sure. I know that is how it works in sql server. I haven't worked with any other DBMS in so long...